# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Not a Hack file. can HHVM run .php file?

Tags: php, hhvm

Just installed HHVM and trying to run a simple index.php file, but getting the error below:

**"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Not a Hack file"**

**Commands that produce the error above**:

hhvm index.php
hhvm --php index.php

**index content:**:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

**hhvm version**:
HipHop VM 4.86.1

Note: I can run a hack file without any issue via command line or via FastCGI.

`hhvm fib.hack (run with no problem)`

Am I missing a flag or a configuration setting?
All the tutorials that I have been able to find online state that hvvm should be able to run php with no issue out of the box.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You'll enter into other issues but as a first step try using `<?hh` instead of `<?php` because it is not allowed in the latest versions of HHVM.  The `.php` extension is still allowed but not the header of the file:

```html
<?hh
phpinfo();
```

After that you'll enter into issues like "**Uncaught Error: Found top-level code**" for which you'll need to wrap the code inside an entry point function by adding the attribute and the function as follows:

```html
<?hh

<<__EntryPoint>>
function main_entry_point(): void {
  phpinfo();
}
```

After that you'll enter into other issues because of the use of `phpinfo()` and other PHP functions because the **HHVM** guys are trying to limit PHP usage for some reason.

Comment: This is a good answer but leaves out the important toplevel detail: HHVM no longer supports PHP, and supports Hack only. The two are still quite closely related so you can get away with transformations like this, but that's why. https://hhvm.com/blog/2018/09/12/end-of-php-support-future-of-hack.html talks about this in more detail.